# In Haskell why can't we compose show and fst

Tags: haskell

I was expecting for `show.fst (1,2)` to work. But am surprised to see it give an exception.

On running individual `fst (1,2)` returns `1::Num a => a` and `show 1` prints out 1 as string

```
show.fst $ (1,2)
```

works fine. Which is even more confusing as I do not see how the tuple can be reduced further (from what I understand the $ operator is used when we want the right part of expression to be evaluated.

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception. It gives you a type error. In a typed language, those are *very* different.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Haskell, function application has higher priority than any operators, so

```
show . fst (1,2)
```

is parsed as

```
show . (fst (1,2))
```

And, since `fst (1,2) == 1` is not a function, it is hard to compose it with anything.

---

The `$` operator is actually just function application, but with a very low priority. This means that, in contrast, this

```
show . fst $ (1,2)
```

if parsed as

```
(show . fst) $ (1,2)
```

which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 6):

Because `.` has lower precedence than function application, `show.fst (1,2)` is equivalent to `show . (fst (1,2))`, which equals `show . 1`, which doesn't make much sense as `1` isn't a function.